# Securing Different Endpoints with Different Users using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm working with a Spring Boot 1.5.2 web application and want to secure the existing API endpoints using HTTP Basic Authentication.

Here is what I've configured so far via Spring Security:

**CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (isCredentialValid(authentication)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString(), Collections.emptyList());
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException("User authentication failed for user " + authentication.getName());
    }

    private boolean isCredentialValid(Authentication authentication) {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User databaseUser = userService.findUserByUsername(username);

        return databaseUser != null && bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(password, databaseUser.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/orders/**").authenticated();
    }
}
```

This works fine for one user but I have the following requirements:

**Requirement 1**

User `demo1` should only have access to the following:

```
POST /orders/info
GET /orders/:id
```

**Requirement 2**

User `demo2` should only have access to the following:

```
POST /orders
```

Comment: it should be handled with `@PreAuthorize` with roles! SecurityConfig should be handling authentication, not authorization, and what you are looking for is authorization :)

Comment: Just a comment, basic authentication isn't remotely secure. The username & password are sent in plain text over the wire. You should look at something https based like OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by doing the following:

1. Assigning a role to each user (`READ_ORDERS` or `SAVE_ORDERS`)
2. Modifying `SecurityConfig` to it just configures basic authentication without any antMatchers
3. Adding method-level security with the `@PreAuthorize` annotation on the methods in the controller class

**CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        User databaseUser = userService.findUserByUsername(username);

        if (isCredentialValid(databaseUser, password)) {
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getCredentials().toString(), getGrantedAuthorities(databaseUser));
        }

        throw new BadCredentialsException("User authentication failed for user " + authentication.getName());
    }

    private boolean isCredentialValid(User databaseUser, String password) {
        return databaseUser != null && bCryptPasswordEncoder.matches(password, databaseUser.getPassword());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(User user) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Role> roles = user.getRoles();

        if (roles != null) {
            for (Role role : roles) {
                grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
            }
        }

        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

**OrderController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/orders")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OrderInfoController {

    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SAVE_ORDERS')")
    public SuccessData saveOrder(@RequestBody SaveOrderRequestData request) {
        // save order code
    }

    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('READ_ORDERS')")
    @RequestMapping("/info")
    public GetOrderHeaderResponseData getOrderHeader(@RequestBody OrderRequestData request) {
        // get order header code
    }

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('READ_ORDERS')")
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public OrderData getOrderDetails(@PathVariable("id") final Long id) {
        // get order details code
    }
}
```